# Pointer problem using header file with struct/array, resulting in multiple defenitions error (C)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have a program (knapsack, optimized for returning the highest value solution with the least weight) for which I want to use external files for the typedef and struct data.

But I can't get it working, somewhere I am messing up with the pointers. I get an 'multiple definition' error or when I change it, I get an 'xxx not declared' error...

*/tmp/ccMy5Yw0.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `item1'*

Any help on pointing out my thinking mistake in greatly appreciated.
(I compiled online @ https://www.onlinegdb.com/)

It did work when I had everything in one file, but after splitting it in different files I can't get it working...

```
main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "defs.h"
#include "data.c"

item_t *items[ITEMS_SIZE] = { &item1, &item2, &item3, &item4, &item5, &item6, &item7, &item8,   &item9, &item10 };

int *knapsack (item_t * items, int n, int w)
{
  int h, h_i, h_j, i, j, a, b, *mm, **m, *s;
  mm = calloc ((n + 1) * (w + 1), sizeof (int));
  m = malloc ((n + 1) * sizeof (int *));
  m[0] = mm;
  h = m[0][0];
  h_i = 0;
  h_j = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
      m[i] = &mm[i * (w + 1)];
      for (j = 0; j <= w; j++)
    {
      if (items[i - 1].weight > j)
        {
          m[i][j] = m[i - 1][j];
        }
      else
        {
          a = m[i - 1][j];
          b = m[i - 1][j - items[i - 1].weight] + items[i - 1].value;
          m[i][j] = a > b ? a : b;
          if (m[i][j] > h)
        {
          h = m[i][j];
          h_i = i;
          h_j = j;
        }
        }
      printf ("%d\t%d\t%d\n", h, h_i, h_j);
    }
    }
  s = calloc (n, sizeof (int));
  for (i = h_i, j = h_j; i > 0; i--)
    {
      if (m[i][j] > m[i - 1][j])
    {
      s[i - 1] = 1;
      j -= items[i - 1].weight;
    }
    }
  free (mm);
  free (m);
  return s;
}

int main ()
{
  int i, n, tw = 0, tv = 0, *s;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      if (items[i]->SwitchOn)
    {
      items[i]->value = items[i]->value;
    }
      else
    {
      items[i]->value = 0;
    }
    }
  n = sizeof (items) / sizeof (item_t);
  s = knapsack (items, n, 690);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (s[i])
    {
      printf ("%-22s %5d %5d\n", items[i]->name, items[i]->weight,
          items[i]->value);
      tw += items[i]->weight;
      tv += items[i]->value;
    }
    }
  printf ("%-22s %5d %5d\n", "totals:", tw, tv);
  return 0;
}
```

defs.h

```
    #ifndef SYSTEMDEFS_H_INCLUDED
    #define SYSTEMDEFS_H_INCLUDED
    
    #define ITEMS_SIZE 10
    
    typedef struct Item
    {
      char name[40];
      int weight;
      int value;
      bool SwitchOn;
    } item_t;
    
    extern item_t item1;
    extern item_t item2;
    extern item_t item3;
    extern item_t item4;
    extern item_t item5;
    extern item_t item6;
    extern item_t item7;
    extern item_t item8;
    extern item_t item9;
    extern item_t item10;
    
    #endif
```

data.c

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "defs.h"

item_t item1 =
{
    .name = "part1",
    .weight = 25,
    .value = 8,
    .SwitchOn = false,
};

item_t item2 =
{
    .name = "part2",
    .weight = 40,
    .value = 2,
    .SwitchOn = true,
};

item_t item3 =
{
    .name = "part3",
    .weight = 60,
    .value = 7,
    .SwitchOn = false,
};

item_t item4 =
{
    .name = "part4",
    .weight = 100,
    .value = 6,
    .SwitchOn = false,
};

item_t item5 =
{
    .name = "part5",
    .weight = 150,
    .value = 2,
    .SwitchOn = true,
};

item_t item6 =
{
    .name = "part6",
    .weight = 380,
    .value = 10,
    .SwitchOn = true,
};

item_t item7 =
{
    .name = "part7",
    .weight = 850,
    .value = 2,
    .SwitchOn = false,
};

item_t item8 =
{
    .name = "part8",
    .weight = 75,
    .value = 15,
    .SwitchOn = true,
};

item_t item9 =
{
    .name = "part9",
    .weight = 800,
    .value = 1,
    .SwitchOn = false,
};

item_t item10 =
{
    .name = "part10",
    .weight = 75,
    .value = 8,
    .SwitchOn = true,
};
```

Comment: Remove #include "data.c" from main.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you included `data.c` in `main.c`

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "data.c"
```

then now the code in `data.c` is duplicated in two translation units: one with `main.c` and other with `data.c`.

Remove this line

```
#include "data.c"
```

from `main.c`.

Also pay attention to thatf you declared an array of the type `item_t *[ITEM_SIZE]`

```
item_t *items[ITEMS_SIZE] = { /*...*/ };
```

So if you will pass it as an argument expression to a function it is implicitly converted to the pointer to its first element of the type `item_t **`.  But you are passing the array to the function `knapsack`

```
s = knapsack (items, n, 690);
```

the first parameter of which has the type `item_t *`.

```
int *knapsack (item_t * items, int n, int w)
```

So the compiler should issue a message that the pointer types are noyt compatible. That is whether the function is declared and defined incorrectly or you are calling it supplying incorrect arguments.

Comment: Dear Vlad, now that part works fine, but the knapsack function doesn't read the values from the array items... All I get are 0's...